# JTextField not updating from Serial Port

Tags: java, swing, serial-port

I'm attempting to write software to read data from three RS232 Serial Ports, and i've written some code to give visual feedback as to which port the program is actually listening on. I know the program is listening on COM1, as i've got it printing to console to tell me which port it's listening to. The issue is that it's not updating the JTextFields to inform the User in the actual GUI. The code i've written is as follows:

```
if (Serial.currPortId == (null)) {
    listenState.setText("NONE");
    listenState.revalidate();
}
while (Serial.currPortId != (null)) {
    listenState.setText(Serial.currPortId.getName());
    listenState.revalidate();
    if (Serial.currPortId.getName().equals("COM1")) {
        tab1sheet.setText(ImportMenu.serialImport.datafeed);
        tab1sheet.revalidate();
    }
    else if (Serial.currPortId.getName().equals("COM2")) {
        tab2sheet.setText(ImportMenu.serialImport.datafeed);
        tab2sheet.revalidate();
    }
    else if (Serial.currPortId.getName().equals("COM3")) {
        tab3sheet.setText(ImportMenu.serialImport.datafeed);
        tab3sheet.revalidate();
    }
    else {tab1sheet.setText("N/A");
          tab1sheet.revalidate();
          tab2sheet.setText("N/A");
          tab2sheet.revalidate();
          tab3sheet.setText("N/A");
          tab3sheet.revalidate();
    }
}
```

For some reason it's only ever setting the "listenState" field to NONE and then not updating, despite claiming to be listening to COM1 in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is breaking Swing threading rules. It may be trying to run the listening code on the Swing event thread (we can't tell based on the snippet you've posted), but it certainly is trying to update the text field in a thread bad way. Instead, I recommend that you use a SwingWorker to listen to the port in a background thread, and specifically a `SwingWorker<Void, String>` using the publish/process method pair to send text to the JTextArea. Or if you need to update the GUI with more complex information going to multiple locations of the GUI, then do so by attaching a PropertyChangeListener to your SwingWorker, which will notify any listeners (the GUI) of changes to the worker's state.

For more, check out [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Your code could look *something* like this:

```
class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
    // properties to listen for changes to:
    public static final String LISTEN_STATE = "listen state";
    public static final String CURRENT_PORT_ID = "current port id";
    public static final String DATA_FEED = "data feed";
    private String listenState = "None";
    private String dataFeed = "";
    private String currentPortId = "";

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        while (true) {
            if (Serial.currPortId != (null)) {
                // change properties when data comes in
                String currPortId = Serial.currPortId.getName();
                setListenState(currPortId);
                setCurrentPortId(currPortId);
                setDataFeed(ImportMenu.serialImport.datafeed);
            } else {
                setListenState("None");
                break; // ??
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getListenState() {
        return listenState;
    }

    public void setListenState(String listenState) {
        // set the prop change parameters
        String oldValue = this.listenState;
        String newValue = listenState;

        // update the propertie's state
        this.listenState = listenState;

        // notify listeners of the change
        firePropertyChange(LISTEN_STATE, oldValue, newValue);
    }

    public String getDataFeed() {
        return dataFeed;
    }

    public void setDataFeed(String dataFeed) {
        // same rationale as for the other setter method
        String oldValue = this.dataFeed;
        String newValue = dataFeed;
        this.dataFeed = dataFeed;
        firePropertyChange(DATA_FEED, oldValue, newValue);
    }

    public String getCurrentPortId() {
        return currentPortId;
    }

    public void setCurrentPortId(String currentPortId) {
        // same rationale as for the other setter method
        String oldValue = this.currentPortId;
        String newValue = currentPortId;
        this.currentPortId = currentPortId;
        firePropertyChange(CURRENT_PORT_ID, oldValue, newValue);
    }
}
```

You could then attach a listener that responds to changes and then updates the display in the GUI

```
private class MyWorkerListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        switch (evt.getPropertyName()) {
        case MyWorker.LISTEN_STATE:
            String listenState = evt.getNewValue().toString();
            // show in text field
            break;
        case MyWorker.CURRENT_PORT_ID:
            String currentPortId = evt.getNewValue().toString();
            // use this to decide which tab to change to
            break;
        case MyWorker.DATA_FEED:
            String dataFeed = evt.getNewValue().toString();
            // show where needed
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and you'd wire it up in the gui like:

```
MyWorker worker = new MyWorker();
worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new MyWorkerListener());
worker.execute();
```

you'd also want to add another PropertyChangeListener to the SwingWorker to listen for the SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE newValue, and when it occurs, call `get()` on the worker to trap and handle any exceptions

Comment: I'll look into this, thank you! The listening code is run in a different class which is called in here via "Serial". It's just a case of getting it to update. I don't have much experience with serial ports so it's all learning.

Comment: @JosephOliver: but are you running the listening code within a background thread? If not, I would expect the code to totally freeze your GUI so that it is completely non-responsive.

Comment: @JosephOliver: please see edit in answer for an incomplete example.